# Transform PointCloud2 doesn't work as expected

Tags: ros, geometry, ros-melodic, sensor-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to transform my pointcloud2 in python like stated [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/9103/how-to-transform-pointcloud2-with-tf/).

But somehow the result is not correct. I am not able to visualize the pointcloud I get as a result in rviz. This is why I tried to just use an empty transformation on my pointcloud and I get some different cloud as a result. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

> ```
> from tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs import do_transform_cloud
> ```

> ```
> def transform_pointcloud(self, pointcloud):
>     trans = TransformStamped()
>     trans.header.stamp = pointcloud.header.stamp
>     trans.header.frame_id = pointcloud.header.frame_id
>     trans.header.seq = pointcloud.header.seq
>     trans.child_frame_id = "corner"
>     trans.transform.translation.x = 0
>     trans.transform.translation.y = 0
>     trans.transform.translation.z = 0
>     trans.transform.rotation.x = 0
>     trans.transform.rotation.y = 0
>     trans.transform.rotation.z = 0
>     trans.transform.rotation.w = 0
>
>     newpointcloud = do_transform_cloud(pointcloud, trans)
>     return newpointcloud
> ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340933/transform-pointcloud2-doesn%27t-work-as-expected/) by [rosNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/50638/rosnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing that jumps to my eye is `trans.transform.rotation.w = 0`: quaternions should be normalized, so this has to be `trans.transform.rotation.w = 1`.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2020-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/50638/rosnewbie/) on 2020-01-03**:
@aPonza omg..so stupid from me. This fixed it. Thanks alot!